# How do I remove this Ksyrium hub body?

Tags: wheels, freehub

I want to get into this hub to lubricate the bushing. Every instruction I see on the Internet says to use a 5 mm Allen and a 17 mm wrench. But there is nothing to put a 17 mm wrench on. There is the internal nut, but I can't get a wrench on that; it is behind the hub shell. Do I have a different version of the wheel? Or am I missing something?[image: picture of freehub with cassette removed]

[image: non drive side]

Comment: Seems very much similar to the [Easton hub](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42085/any-tricks-to-disassembling-an-easton-r4-rear-hub) I was working to disassemble.  Nathan's answer sounds about right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe on this one you put a 5mm wrench in both endcaps and turn counterclockwise. You're trying to get the drive-side endcap off. If it's the non-drive one that breaks free first, there should be a larger size allen fitting in the end of the axle that will be exposed when you take it off. Stick the 6mm or 8mm or whatever it is in that and then you can get the other endcap off, and then the freehub should slide off. Careful not to lose any of the pawls or springs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No 5 mm on the other side, though. Just what looks like holes for a pin spanner maybe. Is that what I'm supposed to use? Of so, any idea what spanner fits it?

Comment: Added picture of non-drive side to show.

Comment: Oops, sorry. That end cap should pull/wiggle out. The pin holes are for adjusting the bearings, and (ideally) use a special Mavic tool.

Comment: Lovely, thank you. It was so firmly on there that it did not seem like it was supposed to come off, but pulling with a bit more confidence it did.

Answer (score 3):

Nathan's answer is correct, with the comments. Here is a picture to show what non drive side looks like with that endcap off. I had to pull pretty hard, but it comes straight off.

[image: non drive side, end cap pulled off]

Comment: Instructions above worked perfectly for 2003 Mavic SLS Krysium free wheel. It is hard to get that plug on the non drive side off. Take your time